# How to put semicolon in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Is the semicolon correct in this sentence?

> Being taught and raised in a society; where art and design is an awful career option, I still manage myself pursuing my inner desire anyway.

Comment: Why the semi-colon? Punctuation at that point in your example is unnecessary. You can't use a semi-colon because "Being taught and raised in a society" cannot stand by itself.

Comment: There should be no semicolon in that sentence; there is only one independent clause and there is no list of phrases/clauses containing internal commas. A single comma before *I* is all that's certainly needed, though another before *pursuing ...* may be called for depending on what exactly that last piece means.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much, So I can just put;   Being taught and raised in a society where art and design is an awful career option, I still manage myself pursuing my inner desire anyway.

Comment: @Lex Yes if what you mean is that what you manage is "myself pursuing my inner desire. If you mean "pursuing my inner desire anyway" to redefine or amplify "managing myself", then it should be preceded by a comma.

Answer (score 3):

A semicolon is used to separate two independent clauses. In this case,

> Being taught and raised in a society

is not an independent clause.

Using your words, I would rephrase your sentence as:

> Being taught and raised in a society where art and design is an awful career option, I still manage myself pursuing my inner desire anyway.

But that is a little wordy. If you *really* want to use a semicolon, you could do:

> I was raised in a society that considered art and design awful career options; despite what they taught me, I still manage myself pursuing my inner desire anyway.